How can i make a dynamic allocated struct (a variable in it) to be allocated in the main function without changing too much the code?
I'm trying to make a struct that will be used to read "databases", but my problem is that the functions are using a defined variable that cannot be changed:
#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 100
But, when I try to make it more dynamic I end up making pointers instead of the fixed length variables, and because they became pointers (name, email, rows) I end up changing the functions that were in the code previously and start to use a lot of memory allocation calls, which results in a lot of errors...
This is the part of the code, working but without being dynamic:
#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 100

struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database {
   struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};

struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};

The other functions read a file (read, write, flush, rewind) and copy data to the file with string n copy.
So, briefly i want a way to change the struct (name, email, rows) to make it arbitrarily sized by the input the user puts in, but without breaking the program or doing excessive calls to memory allocation (which i tried and ended up calling a memory allocation for each row name, email), my goal is to only make dynamic the struct itself, i don't know if maybe with reallocating...
This is from a book (Learning C the hard way exercise 17, i am new to C and stuff alike, so this may be a stupid thing).
This was the code with less calls to memory allocation (i did one with more than these and it worked, until i tried to write a name to a db in it):
/*** headers ***/
#include <stdio.h>      // perror()
#include <assert.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/*** data ***/
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};

struct Database {
    int max_data;
    int max_rows;
    struct Address *rows;
    char *data; // this will hold all names and emails
};

struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};

/*** error handling stuff ***/ 
...

/*** Database stuff ***/
...
void Database_load(struct Connection *conn) {
    fread(&conn->db->max_rows, sizeof(int), 1, conn->file);
    fread(&conn->db->max_data, sizeof(int), 1, conn->file);

    conn->db->rows = malloc(conn->db->max_rows * sizeof(struct Address));
    if (conn->db->rows == NULL)
        die("Unable to allocate memory for rows in load function.");

    conn->db->data = malloc(conn->db->max_rows * (conn->db->max_data * 2));
    if (conn->db->data == NULL)
        die("Unable to allocate memory for data in load.");

    for (int i = 0; i < conn->db->max_rows; i++) {
        fread(&conn->db->rows[i], sizeof(struct Address), 1, conn->file);
    }

    fread(conn->db->data, sizeof(char), conn->db->max_rows * (conn->db->max_data * 2), conn->file);
}

struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode) {
    struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
    if (!conn)
        die("Memory error");

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if (!conn->db)
        die("Memory error");

    if (mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename,"w");
    } else {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+");
        if (conn->file) {
            Database_load(conn);
        }
    }

    if (!conn->file)
        die("Failed to open the file");
}

void Database_create(struct Connection *conn, int max_rows, int max_data) {
    conn->db->max_rows = max_rows;
    conn->db->max_data = max_data;
    conn->db->rows = malloc(max_rows * sizeof(struct Address));
    if (conn->db->rows == NULL)
        die("Failed to allocate memory for rows");

    conn->db->data = malloc(max_rows * (max_data * 2));
    if (conn->db->data == NULL)
        die("Failed to allocate memory for data struct...");

    for (int i = 0; i < max_rows; i++) {
        conn->db->rows[i].id = i;
        conn->db->rows[i].set = 0;
        conn->db->rows[i].name = conn->db->data + i * (max_data * 2);
        conn->db->rows[i].email = conn->db->rows[i].name + max_data;
    }
}

void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email) {
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];
    if (addr->set)
        die("Already set, delete it first");

    addr->set = 1;
    
    char *name_ptr = conn->db->data + id * conn->db->max_data * 2;
    char *email_ptr = name_ptr + conn->db->max_data;

    strncpy(name_ptr, name, conn->db->max_data - 1);
    name_ptr[conn->db->max_data - 1] = '\0';

    strncpy(email_ptr, email, conn->db->max_data - 1);
    email_ptr[conn->db->max_data - 1] = '\0';
}


The code looks fairly complicated and lacks a main function. I suggest to [edit] the question and create a [mre]. Maybe use a main function and a single called function to demonstrate the problem when converting from static to dynamic allocation. Please copy&paste the "lot of errors".

You will run up against some limitations: (1) All elements of an array are the same size. (2) A struct type can have a single "flexible array member" at the end, but the size of the struct type is as if the flexible array has a length of 0 (so the size only includes members before the flexible array member plus any padding between the flexible array member and the previous member).

Since you have made name and email pointers, you will need to allocate space for the data each time you read a record. So you need a way of getting the size of these fields from the database as you read it. As it stands when you call malloc(max_rows * sizeof(struct Address));, the address struct has not yest any space for those two fields.

There's nothing wrong with a fixed maximum string length. Nor is there anything wrong with separate malloc calls per string. (Flexible array members are too clunky for strings IMO.) Alternatively you could introduce some pre-made string library but that adds a lot of extra complexity that you don't need if this is just some learning exercise.

I would use flexible array member for this task.
#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 100

typedef struct 
{
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
}Address ;


typedef struct 
{
    FILE *file;
    size_t capacity;
    Address dataBase[];
}Connection;

Connection *addRecord(Connection **db, const Address *address)
{
    Connection *tmp = NULL;
    size_t newSize = (db && *db) ? (*db) -> capacity + 1 : 1;

    if(db) tmp = realloc(*db, newSize * sizeof(tmp -> dataBase[0]) + sizeof(*tmp) );
    if(tmp)
    {   
        *db = tmp;
        tmp -> dataBase[newSize - 1] = *address;
        tmp -> capacity = newsize;
    }
    return tmp;
}

Connection *delRecord(Connection **db, size_t index)
{
    Connection *tmp = NULL;
    if(db && *db)
    {
        if((*db) -> capacity < index)
        {
            memmove((*db) -> dataBase + index, 
                    (*db) -> dataBase + index + 1, 
                    sizeof((*db) -> dataBase[0]) * ((*db) -> capacity - index - 1));
        }
        tmp = realloc(*db, ((*db) -> capacity - 1) * sizeof((*db) -> dataBase[0]) + sizeof(*tmp));
        if(tmp) *db = tmp;
    }
    return tmp;
}

Of course, you can expand it to allocate memory in chunks (so not every addition to the database will allocate memory) and not deallocate when the record is deleted. You will have to keep the capacity and actual last index taken.

@chux indeed - applied a patch
